Was CP/M 2.1 released, and if so can it still be found?
When I got into CP/M computing it was the CP/M 3 era, so I picked up my understanding of earlier releases second-hand rather than experiencing them in person. My understanding of the history of 2.x versions was that it went something like:

CP/M 2.0: Released to support bigger disk drives than CP/M 1. Proved
to be buggy and was quickly replaced by:
CP/M 2.1: Bugfixed version of 2.0.
CP/M 2.2: Added BDOS function 40 (write random with zero fill). Soon took over from 2.0 and 2.1 and became universal.

It's possible to find the source for 2.0 and 2.2 on gaby.de and compare it to see the bug fixes. But I've never seen either a source or binary distribution of 2.1.
The comments in the 2.0 source give a build date of August 1979. The equivalent comments in the 2.2 source give a build date of February 1980.
The only information I can find about the release of 2.1 is an announcement in InfoWorld of 31 March 1980 (though the assertions about MP/M in the same paragraph seem to cast some doubt on the whole). A month later, on 28 April 1980, "Digital Marketing" are already advertising Pascal/M for CP/M 2.2. So it's quite possible that 2.1 was only out there for a few weeks before being superseded, or that it never shipped at all. Does anyone know if it actually got distributed, and if it did, has it been archived anywhere?
I have searched the Don Maslin archive of CP/M boot disks for the byte sequence B6 77 C9 3E. This byte sequence appears to be common to the CP/M 2.0 and 2.2 implementations of FUNC12 (return version number), and therefore I would expect it to be present in CP/M 2.1 as well. The search finds 8 instances of the sequence where the next byte is 20 (v2.0) and 455 instances where it is 22 (v2.2), but none where it is 21 for v2.1.
(There is at least one unrelated "2.1" version of CP/M that did have a widespread release; the PCW9512 was shipped with in 1987 with a version of CP/M Plus that signs on as "v 2.1". In that case, it's the BIOS version number).

Interesting Question. What falls between those dates would be MP/M 1.1, which IIRC was spring of 1980. Also notable that internal version numbering is kind of weird: CP/M 2.0 introduces a BDOS version call, also predent in MP/M 1.0. For CPM/2.x it returned H=0 and L as 20 and up  (1.x delivered H/L as 0/0), while MP/M had H=1 and L=30.  Kind of screwed. All of that seems to have been decided around the same time. I wouldn't wonder if there was some confusion to be resolved by leaving out CP/M 2.1?

Here some dude shows disk with CP/M 2.1 for TSR-80 model II. https://youtu.be/WrE-N2sG2Ac?t=232  I don't know this is also Pickles & Trout customization for TSR.  1979 Digital Research CP/M 2.1 and 1980 Pickles and Trout.

CP/M 2.1A https://picclick.com/Vintage-1979-Digital-Research-Pickles-Trout-CP-M-21A-135040022142.html

@Nassau Nice find - that certainly seems to answer the question of whether it existed.

I found DEC Rainbow CP/M 80/86 v2.1. No idea if this is what You are looking for. https://archive.org/details/dec-rainbow-cpm-86-80-v-2.1 File dump shows CP/M-86/80 Version V2.10 (1.1)  and https://oldcomputers.dyndns.org/public/pub/mirror/os2site/sw/dec/rainbow/cpm/cpm21/index.html Rainbow CP/M-86/80 V 2.1  System Disk

@Nassau Sadly, I think the "v2.1" on CP/M 86/80 is a BIOS version number; the actual BDOS (which is CP/M-86) reports version 2.2.

At least one distribution labelled as CP/M 2.1 can be found online: Version 2.1 for the Vector Graphic (file VG16.VGI in the '56K Bootable Disk Images' archive).
MOVCPM displays the message CONSTRUCTING 64K CP/M - VERSION 2.10 but the S_BDOSVER call still returns A=20h (v2.0 rather than v2.1). Thus my attempt to search for a BDOS returning A=21h would not have found it.
Binary comparison with a stock v2.0 BDOS shows that two binary patches have been applied:

In GET$BLOCK, there is a bug fix in the code that finds a free block to allocate. The v2.0 code could fail if the start point of the search was near the end of the disk, but all the free space was near the beginning.
In CLOSE, these is a bug fix in the code that finds the next extent of a file. The v2.0 code did not restart the search at the beginning of the directory, and so could fail to find an extent that was in fact present.

The CCP is the same as the CP/M 2.2 CCP (which, in turn, differs only in one byte from the CP/M 2.0 CCP), except that the separator in directory listings has been changed from : to |.
The userland files appear to be identical to those in CP/M 2.0, except for a binary patch to PIP that clears byte 12 of the destination FCB in a couple of places. (The source of what appears to be an earlier version of this patch can be found as pip20pat.asm in the CP/M 2.0 source release at www.cpm.z80.de).
It seems likely, then, that at least this release of CP/M 2.1 was a minimal update of 2.0, created by patching binary files rather than reassembling / recompiling from source.
